# Vuejs how to watch element currentStyle on width changes

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a menu component and componentA but I want to watch when menu expand and collapse in the componentA.

I have defined menuWatcher in the componentA data attribute

```
const ComponentA = {
    data:function(){
        return {
          menuWatcher:(document.getElementById('menu-area').currentStyle || window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('menu-area')))
        };
    },
    watch:{
        "menuWatcher.width"(width){
            alert(width);
        }
    }
};
```

When I expand and collapse menu am expecting the watcher to alert the width but it's not working.

Please can someone suggest a better way of solving this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not recomment doing things like `document.getElementById('menu-area').currentStyle`. This is bad for several reasons.

I would go for:

On the menu component, I would bind the state of the menu to a variable.
This brings two things to the table:

- programmatically switching [styles](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#ad)
- passing state as [props](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html) to children

You may look at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/324636/). I scribbled a primitive version of what you intendend.